# How to rotate just the object being touched in Unity?

Tags: unity, android, touch

For my first steps in Unity I am just trying to rotate some squares when I touch them.

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testskript2 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 2 * 100);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
            Ray r = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y));
            RaycastHit hit0;
            if (Physics.Raycast(r, out hit0, 100f)) {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 100);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It isn't working this way. Any tips?

Comment: Try to ask better questions by telling us exactly *how* it's not working and exactly how you want it to work. "*isn't working this way*" could mean lots of things, and people won't know how to help you.

Comment: "just trying to rotate some squares when I touch them"

isn't working => square not rotating on touch.

Comment: Was mobile. I would like to make a Raycast to check if the touch of my fingers are within an specific object like a square e.g. . So I can use it as an clickable button e.g. that "on button hit" will perform an action

Comment: You're checking whether the mouse ray hits *something* but you never seem to check *what* it hit. The ray might have struck another object in your scene, completely unrelated to this one.